# Shifting blank cells with concealed formula up

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that takes data from the C column and transfers it to column Z. It essentially results in two columns with almost identical values, the only difference is that column Z removes any number under 0 and over 2 from the values in column C. To achieve this, I used the following formula:

`=IF(OR(C3<0, C3>2), "", C3`

While this formula only applies to a single row, I applied it to the entirety of the data in column Z, which outputs an entire column of data lacking in values below 0 or above 2. This information is then reflected in a graph. The issue I am facing is that whenever the formula encounters a value in column C that is below 0 or over 2, it outputs a blank cell in column Z, that, when double-clicked, displays a formula; so really it is not a "blank cell," but a cell which conceals a formula. This messes up my graph since what I think is happening is that the graph detects every blank cell and reads it as a zero value and records it. This results in my graph being full of dots that are near the zero mark. I also do not think that Excel views these blank cells as entirely blank, since when I tried to detect blanks, none of the ones in column Z came up; probably because they have the formula embedded into them.

I tried to find and remove extreme outliers in my data, but it seems I have the same issue except all the extreme outliers are now zero values.

Is it possible to remove these "blank" formula rows and shift all my data upward? Can this be done with a formula?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I just thought of a way to do it, lol.

I changed the formula to `=IF(OR(C3<0, C3>2), "i", C3` which turns every instance of numbers lower than 0 and higher than 2 into the letter 'i'. All formerly blank cells now came up as 'i'. Afterwards, I selected the entirety of column Z, went to Home > 'Find & Select' > 'Go To Special...' then selected "Formulas" and checked "Text", leaving all the other options deactivated. This actually selected all instances of the letter 'i' and left all the cells containing numerical information alone. Pressing 'delete' removed all annoying dots from my graph.

Does anyone know a more efficient way to do this? Perhaps with a formula? We don't even need the values to shift upwards, really. Just need a way to delete all the formula information in those "blank cells" in order to really make them blank.

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look into PowerQuery: https://powerquery.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/  the transformation is stored in the PowerQuery script while the cells contain the result of the transformation (basically you could either have a new column or replace the original column)

Comment: Or use the FILTER function to create a new array excluding the outliers by corresponding criteria: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759